# Cassandra triggers in a multi datacenter environment

Tags: cassandra, triggers, cassandra-3.0

I have a multi-datacenter environment setup in cassandra. I have triggers setup, but the triggers only run on the node that the data was changed on, in only one DC. Cassandra does a good job of data replication though all data centers. But is there a way to setup cassandra triggers so that they run in each data center?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: nope I have not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to datastax cql_reference, Place the custom trigger code (JAR) in the triggers directory on every node.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTrigger.html